# How to auto-generate default UITableView's for Core Data model objects?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I miss Rails' auto-generated views for model objects, based on inspecting the schema.

Is there such a thing for iOS apps with Core Data, presumably using UITableView?  I don't want the final thing, just a Good Enough (TM) UI to get started and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for 'Good Enough' then just use the UITableView Xcode template and then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, do simply:

```
cell.textField.text = [NSString stringFromFormat @"%@ %@ ..."
                                 object.attribute1, object,attribute2, ...];
```

for each attribute in your Core Data model for the object used in the cell.

Also, you do have options for inspecting the core data attributes and relationships.  You could get ambitious and design a CoreDataGoodEnoughCell that would concatenate all the attributes and relationships given an NSEntityDescription.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like the auto-generated views in Rails, at least not built-into the iOS SDK.

Any solution to this end would certainly require quite a bit of work, but is definitely achievable through a generic UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource, and by subclassing UITableViewCell to map data with view tags.